# Magento 2 product collection in special price date

Tags: magento2

I've got two products with special price, but 1 has expired special price period and the other one has no special_to_date field. How can i get product collection with active special price? My code looks like:

```
$collection = $this->_collectionFactory->create()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addFieldToFilter(
            'entity_id',
            array(
                'in' => $product_ids
            )
        )
        ->addFieldToFilter('special_from_date', ['lteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')])
        ->addFieldToFilter('special_to_date', ['gteq' => $now->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'),])
        ->addCategoryFilter($this->getCurrentCategory())
        ->setPageSize($qty)
        ->setCurPage(1);
    return $collection;
```